# Using Thresholding for segmentation

Tags: image, opencv, segment

I am currently using OpenCV 2.9 on Ubuntu 12.04.03 to perform some sort of threshold-based extraction.
So far I performed a threshold `threshold( tmp_gray, tmp_bin, 120, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );` and morphological operation on source image below. I tried varing threshold range but it seems some noise are being picked up.

[image: source image]

and got a mask that looks like

[image: mask image]

I was able to crop the image with something like `src.copyTo( roi, tmp_gray );` to have

[image: roi image]

What I really want however is just the inner image within the white image area. I suspect if I could get the mask right, that would be straight forward.

I would appreciate any guidance that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Haris and @James

Eventually, after obtaining a threshold image

[image: threshold image]

I then use grabcut to obtain

[image: preferred segmented image]

**Note:** I discovered thresholding before using GrabCut produced a much much better result than just using GrabCut or Threshold only

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the image to the HSV colour space, and work with the saturation channel. This gives the following image which will be easy to threshold (due to the more intense ROI)

[image]

Edit: Just tried it with a threshold of ~100 and gives a pretty good result. Im sure there are ways to improve this even further.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try by the following

1. Apply blur() on source before thresholding.
2. Lower the threshold value.
3. Ignore the boarder area by image ROI

Comment: Thanks Haris for the suggestions.
I actually applied a median blur on the source before thresholding.
Please, could you exemplify how to ignore the boarder areas by image ROI.

Comment: It look like threshold with low value say 50 works fine with above image.